# Prove the following statements about limit points are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

We are given a basic definition to begin with: Given $D\subset{R}$ , say $x\in{R}$ is a limit point of $D$ if $D\cap{B_\epsilon(x)}$ is infinite for each $\epsilon>0$.  (Where $B_\epsilon(x)$ denotes the set of all real numbers $z$ with $|x-z|<\epsilon$.)

Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

(a) for every $\epsilon>0$, $D\cap{B_\epsilon(x)}$ is non-empty

(b) $x$ is a limit point of D

(c)  there is a sequence in $D\backslash\{x\}$ which converges to $x$

---

I know I have to show that one implies another, the other implies another one, and then that other one implies my first one (three If-Then proofs).

(b $\implies$ a) Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $D$, thus $D\cap{B_\epsilon(x)}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon>0$, and therefore since this intersection is infinite, it is non-empty.

How do I go about with the other two If-Then proofs?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For $(a)\implies(c)$, pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$. Each integer $n\geq1$ gives a nonempty intersection; use the axiom of choice to pick $a_n$ from that nonempty intersection.

For $(c)\implies(b)$, scrutinize the definition of convergence of a sequence.